# Selectively Modify Indices

Tags: r

Is there a shorter way to select elements and modify them? For example, in

```
y[y < 1] <- y[y < 1]*2
```

the object *y* is referenced 4 times in one line. Is it possible to reduce this repetition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a construct that reduces the number of references to `y` by 1:

```
y <- -2:2
y[i] <- y[i <- y < 1] * 10

y
# [1] -20 -10   0   1   2
```

In practice, though, I'm more likely to do this, which is maybe less "clever" but is certainly much easier to parse (for a human):

```
i <- y < 2
y[i] <- y[i] * 10
```

Comment: Waitaminute, how did you get away with not initializing `i`,first, in the first example?

Comment: `i` is assigned within  `y[i<-y<1]` before it is evaluated in `y[i]`

Comment: @Zach -- Yeah. I've actually seen it a few times in the R sources, and I'd otherwise be tempted to think of it as just a curiosity. It would most likely be useful if you're wanting to write very compact code, and if the tested condition is something more complex/verbose than `y < 1`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
y <- y*{{y<1} + 1}
```

In general you can introduce a function f

```
f <- function(bool) ifelse(bool, 2, 1)
y <- y * f(y < 1)
```

This approach seems a bit faster than Josh's solution

```
n <- 10000
y <- sample(c(1,-1), n, replace = TRUE)
f1 <- function(y){y[i] <- y[i <- y < 1] * 10; y}
f2 <- function(y){y <- y*{{y<1} + 1}; y} 
benchmark(f1(y), f2(y), replications = 50000)
```

> ```
>   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
> 1 f1(y)        50000   30.29    2.398    27.427    3.146          0         0
> 2 f2(y)        50000   12.63    1.000     9.859    2.918          0         0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This does not reduce the number of references to `y`, but it does stop `y>1` being calculated twice

```
y <- ifelse(y<1, y, y *2)
```

or you could predefine y <1

```
replacing <- y < 1
```

Then the line only contains two explicit references to `y`

```
y[replacing] <- y[replacing] *2
```

You could put y in a `data.table`, and then you can (almost) reduce the number of times `y` is repeated by 1

```
 library(data.table)
 Y <- data.table(y = y)

 Y[y <1, y := y*2]
```

I say almost, because if you want to access the atomic vector `y`, you will need to type `Y[,y]`